# NestJS + TypeORM one column relations in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have a many to many relation Post <-> Tag, and I would like to generate a list of Posts. Each post should contain a list of its slug tags. But this list should be that type : string[]

Here are my entities

```
@Entity()
export class Post {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    @IsDefined()
    title: string;

    @Column()
    @IsDefined()
    text: string;

    @Column()
    slug: string;

    @ManyToMany(type => Tag)
    @JoinTable()
    tags: Tag[];
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Tag {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    slug: string;

}
```

The code in my service

```
this.postsRepository.createQueryBuilder("post")
      .select(["post.slug", "post.title", "tags.slug"])
      .leftJoin("post.tags", "tags")
      .getMany()
```

Result I have

```
[{
    "title": "Post 1",
    "slug": "post-1",
    "tags": [{
        "slug": "tag-1"
    }]
}, {
    "title": "Post-2",
    "slug": "post-2",
    "tags": [{
        "slug": "tag-1"
    }, {
        "slug": "tag-2"
    }]
}]
```

Result I want

```
[{
    "title": "Post 1",
    "slug": "post-1",
    "tags": ["tag-1"]
}, {
    "title": "Post-2",
    "slug": "post-2",
    "tags": ["tag-1", "tag-2"]
}]
```

Is it possible ?
Actually I would like to do the same than loadRelationIds

```
this.postsRepository.find({ select: ["slug", "title"], loadRelationIds: true })
```

but with my slugs.